# toastr js with SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, toastr

I am trying to use toastr js in SharePoint 2013 to show notifications. Everything looks great until I add closebutton:true in toastr option. Close button appears though the alignment gets distorted for the title, message and the close button. Any idea what is going wrong with the implementation?

With closed button
[image: With closed button]

without closed button
[image: without closed button]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It occurs since SharePoint (`core15.css`) declares `min-width` property for `button`:

```
input[type=button], input[type=reset], input[type=submit], button {
   min-width: 6em;
}
```

**Solutions**

CSS:

```
button.toast-close-button {
  min-width: 0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('button.toast-close-button').css('min-width',0);
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a CSS issue. My guess is that some style on your site is interfering with the styles in toastr. You should be able to fix it by checking the styles in the Chrome Dev Tools (or whatever browser tools you use) to inspect the CSS, find the style that is causing the issue (toggle them on and off to help), and then create a new style to override the problem.